# Multiple Django Forms on Single Page

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a form to input scores for a round of golf. A standard round of golf is 18 holes, so the form should create 18 instances of 'Score' once submitted. How would I go about creating a form that contains a single dropdown for 'player' and 18 text fields for strokes on each hole? Below are the models being used:

```
class Score(models.Model):
    hole = models.ForeignKey(Hole, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    strokes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Hole(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Could you please list the specific challenges you experienced while creating such a form? Without the details your question seems vague and looks like you're asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: After learning more about formsets, my challenge currently is that if I use formsets to put 18 Score forms on a page, I'd like to use a single dropdown for Player, and have that apply to all 18 forms. Currently, I'd have to select a Player 18 times on the page. Or, if I put a single drop down, it only applies to the first form. I understand why those two scenarios occur, but I'm not sure how to approach using a single Player dropdown and have it apply to all 18 Score entries.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Django Inline Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). This allows you to include multiple forms per view and the inline formset allows you to work with objects related by a foreign key.

It is relatively easier when you know the exact amount of forms you need to include in your template. However, if you want to dynamically include forms in your template then you will need to look into adding some javascript to provide this functionality.

Comment: I took a look at inline formsets. This is definitely what I needed. On the template, how would you approach using a single drop down menu for Player, and have that selection apply to all 18 forms?